# Gmod addon trouble?

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

A few days ago I joined a Gmod server. It had an addon that removes your 3rd person from vehicles and adds realistic first person. I wouldn't have a problem with that if it hadn't made all my pills first person! Can anyone tell me the position of the folder where the addons you get from servers are stored or the addons name and position?

Answer (score 1):

In the following path, `%STEAMROOT%` refers to your Steam install location, eg. `C:/Program Files/Steam`, and `%STEAMUSER%` refers to the name that you use to log into Steam. (These aren't environment variables Steam sets, so you'll have to replace them yourself.)

The install location for Garry's Mod addons is `%STEAMROOT%/steamapps/%STEAMUSER%/garrysmod/garrysmod/addons`.

Comment: Yes I know where my addons are but i have millions of them! Cant somebody just tell me the name of the addon so i can search for it and delete it?

Comment: So seriously now, were do the addons that you were forced to download by admins go? Please awnser my question! I really hate that addon!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution. I picked the addons I liked the most, went on www.garrysmod.org and downloaded them and I deleted my addons folder.